# AngularJS Filters; Format a number to a string, but not vice versa?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter, type-conversion

I read here that an Angular JS filter is:

1. `number` Format a number to a string.

As a result I would expect a filter to perform the opposite conversion, i.e. from string to number. However, I cannot find that filter.

---

Here is a random, desperate attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">

<p>String to number {{ str | number }}</p>
<p>Number to string {{ num | string }}?</p> <!--This must be the problem -->

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.str = "3.14";
    $scope.num = 3.14;
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

which gives:

```
String to number {{ str | number }}

Number to string {{ num | string }}?
```

If I use only the `number` filter, the output is 3.14.

Comment: You need to create a custom filter to achieve the mentioned functionality.
You can read about it here: 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters

Comment: There's no Angular filter because javascript already has .toString(). `Number to string {{ num.toString() }}`.

Comment: And `parseInt()` also @Lex, so I don't really get your point, sorry! Envision thanks!

Comment: The point is, `parseInt()` doesn't allow you to specify the number of decimals for display like `| number` does. They aren't equivalent like `.toString()` and the [non-existent] `| string` would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter), there is no build-in filter for string.
Though you could very easily build up a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a custom filter to do it.

```
myApp.filter('string', function() {
  return function(input) { 
    return input.toString();
  };
});
```

Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/zp15ht3u/2/